# ADF Combo-box behave un normal

Tags: oracle-adf

i created cascade LOVs ,

ex: subjects depend on faculties depend on branches,

faculties and branches are choice lists, subjects is combo-box with list of values.

when user write some text in subjects combo-box and press enter key from keyboard, if the subjects contains that text it will open search dialog to make user choose one of those filtered rows.

combo box already do that and open the search dialog with filtered and correct data as i need, but i face problem, the search dialog closes without any action by it's own.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there any partial triggers on the combo box, once try removing that and change it's ppr to none.